# How can my macbook be able to ping google but not my router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bash, router

I've been having a lot of trouble recently with my macbook dropping internet connection intermittently. Every 5 minutes or so. So I've been trying to determine where the failure is occurring. Virgin Media ran me through a factory reset of my SuperHub yesterday, and the problem seemed to resolve itself for a bit, but this morning the same problem is back.

My diagnosis has gotten as far as the following command:

```
ping -c 5 127.0.0.1 && ping -c 5 192.168.0.1 && ping -c 5 8.8.8.8 && ping -c 5 www.reddit.com
```

This results in the following output:

```
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.057 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.071 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.126 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.120 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.077 ms

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.057/0.090/0.126/0.028 ms
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3

--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

Since this stops the bash command, I then run the rest of the command separately.

```
ping -c 5 8.8.8.8 && ping -c 5 www.reddit.com
```

And get:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=54 time=17.944 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=18.489 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=19.976 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=17.432 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=15.882 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 15.882/17.945/19.976/1.337 ms
PING www.reddit.com (198.41.208.138): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 198.41.208.138: icmp_seq=0 ttl=58 time=10.835 ms
64 bytes from 198.41.208.138: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=40.317 ms
64 bytes from 198.41.208.138: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=12.355 ms
64 bytes from 198.41.208.138: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=12.904 ms
64 bytes from 198.41.208.138: icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=18.540 ms

--- www.reddit.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 10.835/18.990/40.317/10.978 ms
```

How is it possible that I can't ping my router `192.168.0.1` but can ping google at `8.8.8.8`?? Does it suggest what the problem might be?

To confirm, I understand that 192.168.0.1 is the router, since that is what network preferences shows as the connected router IP, and is also the default on Virgin Media SuperHubs.

ifconfig output for en0 is:

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 34:36:3b:cb:22:9c
    inet 192.168.0.4 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

I have removed the line about inet6 address, because of [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.hex1.ru/questions/30767802/could-sharing-ifconfig-information-publicly-be-dangerous).

Comment: The output of `iconfig /all` would confirm your network settings are as you say they are. Also, it's possible that the firewall settings on the router are (stupidly) blocking ICMP on the LAN interface.

Comment: I would check your firewall settings on the router. Most of the time it does fix the problem you are having.  Login to you router and go to your firewall settings and see if the ICMP is ticked.

Comment: Yeah, if `pathping reddit.com` does not show your router after your host, ICMP is most probably disabled on your router.

Comment: Followed your advice, you were probably right. But have assumed that the first login after a factory reset might enable ICMP, since I didn't change any settings. Still getting dropouts but now at least I can see a constant connection with the router when they happen. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you get to its web page at 192.168.0.1? Long-term, I'd think about dropping that Superhub to pure modem mode - which will shift it to 192.168.100.1 - but then allow you much more flexibility with a decent router behind it.

Comment: @nickbdyer Please traceroute 8.8.8.8. I'm suspicious I know the answer but would like some clarity.

Comment: Should I be wary of posting that information online? I know very little about hacking, but I imagine that information on the route to my computer might be unadvisable? Or am i being over cautious?

Comment: @Linef4ult I have no doubt of your good intentions I should add!

Comment: Some devices need you to enable ping requests on the device, depending on brand and model.

Answer (score 0):

ICMP requests can be denied at many levels - the host, consumer networking equipment, and beyond (upstream). There are [many reasons](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22711/is-it-a-bad-idea-for-a-firewall-to-block-icmp/22713) to do so, and it's commonplace for certain devices/OS to behave this way by default.

If you are confident in the IP addresses you've provided in your post, you may check the device for such configuration.